# Django Rest Framework how to save a manyToMany with Related Field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have some problem with Django Rest Framework and `manyToMany` relation  with Related Field. Whenn i list I have a error and when I save, it fill data in `database`but it cant display the result.

My model.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=3)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey('ProductState', default=1)
    tax = models.ForeignKey('Tax')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('ProductCategory')

class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    tax = models.ForeignKey('Tax')

class Order(models.Model):
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey('OrderState')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    orderproducts = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='OrderProduct')
```

my serializer.py

```
class OrderProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = OrderProduct
        exclude = ()
        read_only_fields = ('order','tax',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        product = validated_data.pop('product')
        return OrderProduct.objects.create(tax=product['product'].tax, **product)

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orderproducts = OrderProductSerializer(many=True, required=True)
    def create(self, validated_data):
        products = validated_data.pop('orderproduct')
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for product in products:
            op = OrderProduct.objects.create(product=product['product'], tax=product['product'].tax, order=order, qty=product['qty'] )
            op.save()
        order.save()
        return order;

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        exclude = ()
        read_only_fields = ()

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories = ProductCategorySerializer(many=True, required=True)
    tax = TaxSerializer(many=False, required=True)
    state = OrderStateSerializer(many=False, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ()
```

and my view.py

```
class ClientOrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
```

when i try to list I get this error:

> Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/order/
>       Exception Value: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `product` on serializer `OrderProductSerializer`.
>       The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Product` instance.
>       Original exception text was: 'Product' object has no attribute 'product'.
>       Request information:

Comment: I notice one thing, you have a typo: `products = validated_data.pop('orderproduct')`, should be `products = validated_data.pop('orderproducts')` because `orderproducts` is your field name

Comment: you have to rename product to product_set   in  OrderProductSerializer  because its reverse relationship. It will solve the issue of  AttributeError